# Prolog - jigoku solver - run time

Tags: prolog, runtime, sudoku, clpfd

I'm a total newbie to Prolog (as in: I've only done the Prolog chapter in 7 languages in 7 weeks), so general comments to any of the code below are very welcome.

First of all: What is a jigoku? It's like a sudoku, except that you get an empty grid, and within each 3x3 block, inequalities between adjacent slots are given. Example here: http://krazydad.com/jigoku/books/KD_Jigoku_CH_8_v18.pdf. You still need to fill up the grid such that each row, column and block contains the numbers 1-9.

I've tried to implement a solver based on this sudoku solver: http://programmablelife.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/prolog-sudoku-solver-explained.html. For debugging reasons, I started with a 4x4 example that works really well:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

small_jidoku(Rows, RowIneqs, ColIneqs) :-
  Rows = [A,B,C,D], 
  append(Rows, Vs), Vs ins 1..4,
  maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
  transpose(Rows, Columns),     
  maplist(all_distinct, Columns),
  blocks(A, B), blocks(C,D), 
  maplist(label, Rows),
  fake_check_ineqs(Rows, RowIneqs),
  fake_check_ineqs(Columns, ColIneqs),
  pretty_print([A,B,C,D]).      

blocks([], []).       
blocks([A,B|Bs1], [D,E|Bs2]) :-     
  all_distinct([A,B,D,E]),      
  blocks(Bs1, Bs2).

fake_check_ineqs([],[]).
fake_check_ineqs([Head|Tail], [Ineq1|TailIneqs]) :- 
    Head = [A,B,C,D],
    atom_chars(Ineq1, [X1,X2]),
    call(X1, A, B),
    call(X2, C, D),
    fake_check_ineqs(Tail, TailIneqs).

pretty_print([]).
pretty_print([Head | Tail]) :-
 print(Head),
 print('\n'),
 pretty_print(Tail).
```

I then solve the following example:

```
time(small_jidoku([[A1,A2,A3,A4],[B1,B2,B3,B4],[C1,C2,C3,C4],[D1,D2,D3,D4]],[><,<>,<<,<<],[><,<<,<>,>>])).
```

This runs in about 0.5 seconds tops. However, I've also tried to solve it with

```
time(small_jidoku([A,B,C,D],[><,<>,<<,<<],[><,<<,<>,>>])).
```

and this seems to take ages. 
**Can anyone explain why it takes the solver much longer when I don't specify that each row has 4 elements?** My naive answer to this is that Prolog, if not told the actual format of my rows, will also try to explore smaller/bigger rows, hence wasting time on e.g. rows of length 5, but is this actually true?

My second question is about the 9x9 version, that is very much like the 4x4 except that the blocks are of course bigger and that there is more testing to be done when checking inequalities. The code is below:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

jidoku(Rows, RowIneqs, ColIneqs) :-  
  Rows = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],   
  append(Rows, Vs), Vs ins 1..9,
  maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
  transpose(Rows, Columns),     
  maplist(all_distinct, Columns),         
  blocks(A, B, C), blocks(D, E, F), blocks(G, H, I),     
  maplist(label, Rows),
  check_ineqs(Rows, RowIneqs),
  check_ineqs(Columns, ColIneqs),
  pretty_print([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]).      

blocks([], [], []).       
blocks([A,B,C|Bs1], [D,E,F|Bs2], [G,H,I|Bs3]) :-     
  all_distinct([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]),      
  blocks(Bs1, Bs2, Bs3).

check_ineqs([],[]).
check_ineqs([Head|Tail], [Ineq1|TailIneqs]) :- 
    Head = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],
    atom_chars(Ineq1, [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6]),
    call(X1, A, B),
    call(X2, B, C),
    call(X3, D, E),
    call(X4, E, F),
    call(X5, G, H),
    call(X6, H, I),
    check_ineqs(Tail, TailIneqs).
```

The test example:

```
    time(jidoku([[A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9],
        [B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9],
        [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9],
        [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9],
        [E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9],
        [F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9],
        [G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9],
        [H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9],
        [I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9]], 
        [<>>><>,<<<>><,<<<><>,<><<><,>>><><,><>><>,<>>><>,<>><><,><<>>>], 
        [<<<><>,><<>>>,<><<><,><<<>>,><><<<,<><><>,<>>>><,><><><,<>><>>])).
```

and this one has been running overnight without reaching any conclusion and at this point, I have no clue whatsoever what is going wrong. I expected some scaling issues, but not of this proportion!

It would be great if someone who actually knows what they're doing could shine a light on this! Thanks already!

Comment: You should post *all* constraints *before* using `labeling/2` to use the constraint solver to its fullest potential. See the [CLP(FD) manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for more information, in particular section A.8.7.: _Enumeration predicates and search_. Currently, you are only using "generate and test", without much constraint propagation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried to move the labeling to right before the print, but then the check_ineqs complains that the arguments for </2 are not sufficiently instantiated.

Comment: Simply use the CLP(FD) constraints `(#<)/2` and `(#>)/2` instead of the more primitive arithmetic functions. This is also explained in the manual with examples. Hint: `atom_chars(Atom, Cs), maplist(primitive_declarative, Cs, Ds), ...`.

Comment: That really fixed it! I wasn't fancy enough to use maplist here, I just changed my code to:
     atom_chars(Ineq1, [X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6]),
 atom_concat(#,X1,Y1),
        call(Y1, A, B),
and analogous for the rest of course. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the version of your code I had in mind (other predicates kept unchanged):

```
ineqs(Cells, Ineq) :-
        atom_chars(Ineq, Cs),
        maplist(primitive_declarative, Cs, Ds),
        ineqs_(Ds, Cells).

ineqs_([], _).
ineqs_([Op1,Op2|Ops], [A,B,C|Cells]) :-
        call(Op1, A, B),
        call(Op2, B, C),
        ineqs_(Ops, Cells).

primitive_declarative(<, #<).
primitive_declarative(>, #>).
```

Notice that it does not do the generality of the code justice to call the predicate "`check_...`", because the predicate states *what holds* and can be used in several directions: Yes, it can be used to *check* if the constraints hold, but it can *also* be used to state that the constraints *must* hold for some variables. I therefore avoid imperatives and use more declarative names.

You use `ineqs/2` in `jidoku/3` with: `maplist(ineqs, Rows, RowsIneqs)` etc.

Your example and the result with the new version, using SWI 7.3.2:

```
?- length(Rows, 9), maplist(same_length(Rows), Rows),
   time(jidoku(Rows,
   [<>>><>,<<<>><,<<<><>,<><<><,>>><><,><>><>,<>>><>,<>><><,><<>>>],
   [<<<><>,><<>>>,<><<><,><<<>>,><><<<,<><><>,<>>>><,><><><,<>><>>])),
   maplist(writeln, Rows).
% 2,745,471 inferences, 0.426 CPU in 0.432 seconds (99% CPU, 6442046 Lips)
[1,5,4,8,7,2,6,9,3]
[2,3,9,1,6,5,7,4,8]
[6,7,8,3,9,4,2,5,1]
[3,4,1,2,5,6,8,7,9]
[9,6,5,7,1,8,3,2,4]
[8,2,7,9,4,3,1,6,5]
[4,9,3,6,2,1,5,8,7]
[7,8,2,5,3,9,4,1,6]
[5,1,6,4,8,7,9,3,2]
Rows = [[1, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 6, 9|...], ...].
```

In fact, note that *no labeling at all* is required to compute the unique solution in this particular case, because the constraint solver is strong enough to reduce all domains to singleton sets.

In your previous version, all the time was needlessly wasted naively generating permutations that were eventually seen to be inconsistent. With the new version, the constraint solver has a chance to apply this knowledge earlier.

It is therefore recommended to first state all constraints, and only then to invoke `labeling/2` to search for concrete solutions, as explained in the [CLP(FD) manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).

Comment: Thank you! It's great to see such beautiful code and I'm definitely going to read up on all the stuff you used that I've never heard of. Thanks for making my baby Prolog steps a little less painful!

Comment: Great! Notice that all language elements I am using already appear in your original snippet too. Finally, regarding your other question: "Why does it take the solver much longer when I don't specify that each row has 4 elements?" Your suspicion that it will also try to explore smaller/bigger rows in that case is absolutely correct. Moreover, it does so *unfairly* and will *never* reach the layout required in this particular puzzle without your guidance. See the answers for the goal `?- append([A,B,C,D], Ls).`, which appears in your snippet. As often, it's more about *termination* than speed.